# Consolidate row by row from different sheets with different number of records into master sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple worksheets with the number of rows are vary in each sheet but the column names are same, how do I append row by row (means 1st row comes from 1st sheet, then 2nd row should append as to come from 2nd sheet, and 3rd row is append in such a way that comes from 3rd sheet and goes on)into a master sheet which contains all the rows one by one getting from multiple sheets. could someone help me on this issue
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow is not a "write-my-code-for-me" service.

That said, here is code I have already written for this exact purpose. Note that it does not check to ensure the columns line up... it just assumed they all line up correctly. If you have only 1 tab selected, it will merge all visible tabs. If you have multiple tabs selected, it will merge only those tabs.

It also doesn't check to make sure you're entering a sheet name that doesn't already exist and will throw an error if you enter an existing name.

This version assumes every tab has headers and excludes the first row on subsequent tabs:

```
Public Sub MergeTabs()

'Merges selected tabs (or all visible tabs if only 1 selected) in current workbook into a new tab

Dim i As Integer, wb As Workbook, w As Window, wsTo As Worksheet, wsFrom As Collection   'Worksheet collection
Dim strScope As String, strNewTab As String
Dim raTarget As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set w = ActiveWindow

Set wsFrom = New Collection

If w.SelectedSheets.Count = 1 Then
    For i = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count
        If wb.Worksheets(i).Visible Then wsFrom.Add wb.Worksheets(i)
    Next
    strScope = "ALL VISIBLE"
Else
    For i = 1 To w.SelectedSheets.Count
        If w.SelectedSheets(i).Visible Then wsFrom.Add w.SelectedSheets(i)
    Next
    strScope = wsFrom.Count & " SELECTED"
End If

strNewTab = InputBox("Merge data from " & strScope & " sheets to new sheet named:", "Merge tabs", "All")
If strNewTab = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

Set wsTo = wb.Worksheets.Add(wsFrom(1), Count:=1) 'Add before first selected sheet
wsTo.Name = strNewTab

wsFrom(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
wsTo.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False

For i = 2 To wsFrom.Count
    wsFrom(i).Range("A2", wsFrom(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Cells(wsFrom(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Cells.Count)).Copy
    wsTo.Cells(wsTo.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i

wsTo.Range("A1").Select

MsgBox "Merge Done"

End Sub
```

This version assumes there are no headers (or only headers on the first tab):

```
Public Sub MergeTabs()

'Merges selected tabs (or all visible tabs if only 1 selected) in current workbook into a new tab

Dim i As Integer, wb As Workbook, w As Window, wsTo As Worksheet, wsFrom As Collection   'Worksheet collection
Dim strScope As String, strNewTab As String
Dim raTarget As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set w = ActiveWindow

Set wsFrom = New Collection

If w.SelectedSheets.Count = 1 Then
    For i = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count
        If wb.Worksheets(i).Visible Then wsFrom.Add wb.Worksheets(i)
    Next
    strScope = "ALL VISIBLE"
Else
    For i = 1 To w.SelectedSheets.Count
        If w.SelectedSheets(i).Visible Then wsFrom.Add w.SelectedSheets(i)
    Next
    strScope = wsFrom.Count & " SELECTED"
End If

strNewTab = InputBox("Merge data from " & strScope & " sheets to new sheet named:", "Merge tabs", "All")
If strNewTab = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

Set wsTo = wb.Worksheets.Add(wsFrom(1), Count:=1) 'Add before first selected sheet
wsTo.Name = strNewTab

wsFrom(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
wsTo.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False

For i = 2 To wsFrom.Count
    wsFrom(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
    wsTo.Cells(wsTo.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i

wsTo.Range("A1").Select

MsgBox "Merge Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: H thank you very much, but the query is not working even after selecting multiples sheets, it's bringing the data from only one-sheet

Comment: It also assumes all data starts in cell A1 in each sheet. All all sheets in the same workbook and each with data starting in A1?

Comment: yes, I have all sheets in the same workbook, and the data started with cell A1 in each sheet, contains column names in each sheet in the first row and rest of the rows are having data, but my issue is how to get and append 1st row comes from the first sheet, then 2nd row should append that should come from 2nd sheet of the first row, 3rd row should append as next row which comes from 3rd sheet first row  and goes on in this manner, thanks for your kind helping

Comment: It also assumes there are no gaps in rows or columns. That's the only other thing I can see that could prevent the code working. It works fine for me. You might have to step through the code to check what happens when it tries to copy from the additional sheets. You'll be able to see the range that is being copied.

Comment: the sheets doesn't have any blanks/gaps in rows/columns, but still not able to get the right output from this code if you have any sample file, could you please attach it with end result

Comment: oh, it also assumes the column headers exist on every tab. if you don't have any column headers on later tabs, only data, it will skip the first row of data. and if you only have 1 row of data, then nothing will be copied. i'll put in a 2nd version of the code that handles no headers on later sheets.